# If max true in one cell, show the value of another cell in a new cell

Tags: worksheet-function

[image]

I have a table of dates and figures (column A is the date, column B is the figure).

I have 2 cells that show the max and min of column B.

I'd like to be able to show the date from column A next to the cell that shows the max of column B so that I can quickly see what date the max occurred on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure where to start to be honest .... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX and MATCH functions to retrieve the value. Adapt the following formula

```
=INDEX(A1:A16,MATCH(B19,B1:B16,0))
```

[image]

You can also use the XLOOKUP function:

```
=XLOOKUP(B19,B1:B16,A1:A16,,0)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help, just what I needed.

Comment: @Nick If the question has been successfully answered, You can accept the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)